# help with header files in C

Tags: c, header, struct

Ok, I have a pretty good understanding of how header files are to be used in C programs but I keep having this problem that I can't seem to get around. Here is the situation:

Device.c contains `#include "Device.h"`

Device.h contains a definition for a struct and the following...

```
#ifndef DEVICE_H
#define DEVICE_H
#include "SubDevice.h"
typedef struct {
    subDevice * subDevice1;
    subDevice * subDevice2;
} device;
#endif
```

SubDevice.c contains `#include SubDevice.h`

SubDevice.h contains the definition of the subDevice struct and the following...

```
#ifndef SUBDEVICE_H
#define SUBDEVICE_H
#include "Device.h"
typedef struct{
    int MyInt;
    double MyDouble;
}subDevice;
#endif
```

The problem is that I get a compiler error in Device.h in my struct definition. At the line `subDevice * subDevice1;` it says `syntax error before subDevice`.

Is the problem that I am including the header file of the other file in each file? I thought the #ifndef - #define statements would prevent that from causing a problem...

Comment: i don't think `#include DEVICE_H` is correct.

Comment: does the struct in SubDevice.h actually have a name?

Comment: opps, I missed that in my post. I edited it.

Comment: It's still wrong - change: `#include DEVICE_H` to `#include "Device.h"` or whatever you need in the actual header.

Comment: @Jordan S: Are you sure the semicolon is also present in your actual source.

Comment: Is there any reason for using multiple headers in the first place? Would something ever include Device but not Subdevice, especially since you have one including the other? (thus creating a circular reference)..

Answer (score 4):

It's not a header problem. There is a problem on one `typedef`  you have in `SubDevice.h`. So, do change:

```
typedef struct{
    int MyInt;
    double MyDouble;
}
```

To:

```
typedef struct{
    int MyInt;
    double MyDouble;
} subDevice;
```

Your problem should be gone.

Comment: changed it. That what I actually had in my program.

Comment: What is `#include DEVICE_H` in `SubDevice.h`?

Answer (score 2):

You must put a semicolon after the declaration of a `struct`, and your `typedef` is missing the second parameter.

---

**EDIT** to reflect OP's edit

You're including `DEVICE_H`, which is an macro.

You need to include `"device.h"`:

```
#include "device.h"
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have a circular reference.

I guess your main file looks something like this:

```
#include "Subdevice.h"
#include "Device.h"
int main() {}
```

Because of how the C preprocessor works (and how you use the include guards), the contents of `Device.h` will be read before `Subdevice.h`, meaning that the `subDevice` struct has yet to be defined when you define the `device` struct.

Remove the `#include "Device.h"` from `Subdevice.h` and it should compile OK.

Answer (score 1):

You have "typedef struct {...}" in your subdevice.h, when you should have "typedef struct {...} subDevice;"

The line "#include DEVICE_H" also looks somewhat wrong. Did you mean #include "device.h"?

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to be missing is a good understanding of the compilation model used by C (and C++) compilers.
Compiling a C or C++ source file can be separated in three stages:

1. Preprocessing
2. Compiling
3. Linking

#### Preprocessing

During preprocessing, the compiler (or separate preprocessor) goes over the source file and performs macro expansion and `#include` replacements.
All `#include` directives are replaced by the contents of the referenced file.
All macro definitions are processed and where a macro invocation occurs in the text, it is substituted with the replacement text. This is a completely textual process.

After preprocessing, there are no preprocessor directives (lines starting with a `#`) left in the source code

#### Compiling

During compilation, the compiler interprets the source code according to the rules of the C (or C++) language and translates the code to object code.

#### Linking

During the linking phase, all object files are combined together and linked with the relevant libraries to create an executable.

---

The source code presented here has two problems:

1. The subdevice.h file contains a spurious `#include DEVICE_H` directive. This should be reported by the preprocessor/compiler, because `DEVICE_H` does not resolve to a filename in quotes or angle-brackets.
2. There is a missing semi-colon (`;`) (and a missing typedef name) at the end of the typedef in subdevice.h. As a result, the compiler tries to combine this with the next lines of code it sees (the `typedef struct` in device.h) and gets terribly confused. This triggers the syntax error message.

Answer (score 1):

One good way of debugging your code with preprocessor errors is to `gcc -E <files>`, so that you can actually see what would your program look like after that preprocessor is done with it.